# How to monitor the performance of InfluxDb and Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, influxdb, metrics

I am creating a system that uses Apache Kafka queue and InfluxDB database. The system collects measurement data from sensors. I would like to know how I could monitor:

- database load,
- database performance,
- execution time of queries performed on the database
- length of the queue in Topic.

Comment: Do you want to monitor Kafka with InfluxDB? Or store in InfluxDB metrics arriving in a Kafka topic?

Comment: I would like to monitor the database load and memory usage based on the intensity of the data coming from kafka.

Answer (score 1):

1-3 : Try [Prometheus Metrics](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/reference/internals/metrics/) exposed by the server. You can either install a separate Prometheus Server for monitoring, or I think you can use Telegraf to scrape the data to write metrics back to InfluxDB.

4 - Topic sizes are hard to determine, but you can add Prometheus JMX Exporter to the Kafka Brokers or (JVM-based) consumers to (partially) construct such useful information. Tools like Burrow also exist for exporting Kafka Consumer Lag. Then again, setup Prometheus server / Telegraf to scrape these endpoints.